# How to configure automatic addition of dynamic subdomains in symfony 2.8

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I am working on a symfony2.8 application where multiple clients can register themselves and have their own unique subdomain (eg. `clientname.myapp.com`), so that their users can register themselves by using the sign-up form on their homepage. Since the number of clients getting registered would be large in number, I want the addition of subdomains to be automatic rather than doing it manually in `parameters.yml`.
"All clients will be sharing same code and database". So far I have manually inserted a subdomain name in the database, and have saved the url in the etc/hosts file as `127.0.0.1 rgpv.myapp.com`. On my local machine, when I enter the given url, my 'domainListener' picks it up, calls the 'ClientResolver' service and filter out only the subdomain name. And then subdomain name is looked up in the database, if it exists then a personalized homepage is displayed. However if any other url that hasn't been saved in the etc/hosts file, is entered then 'domainListener' does not even picks it up(I guess). I just get a blank page in production environment and a 404 Not Found in development environment. How do I make sure that the subdomains get added automatically on the fly(dynamically)?

Comment: Check this: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html

Comment: @Pavel Well its a start. Thank you :)